# Have a property in an entity which contains the total number of children of a relationship entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Question entity and an Answer entity. I want the question to have a property which contains the number of answers it has.

I know I can define the relationship in Question so that all the answers are loaded together with the question, but that's not very efficient. I load all the answers for a question in a separate request.

I know I can also count how many answers (using a Repository method) a question has but I'd like to have that logic coupled to the Question entity so that ideally both the count of answers and loading the question object are done in the same SQL query by the JPA, otherwise the request has to execute 20 SELECT COUNT queries only to get the number of answers per question because 20 questions are loaded each time.

Is this possible the achieve with Spring JPA?

Comment: Does `Question` have an `Answers` collection? If yes, you can have methods such as `addAnswer` and so forth on `Question` which keep the total number, and later persists that as an attribute. You would probably want this anyway if you are dealing with objects rather than anemic data structures.

Comment: But that will trigger the first issue: that all the answers will be loaded together with the question from the database, only to be able to count the total number.

Comment: If using Hibernate - a. Add `@OneToMany Set<Answer> answers` to `Question`. b. Add `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` to `answers`. Then, `question.getAnswers().size()` will simply issue a `SELECT COUNT(answer) ...` query, without loading answers for each question.

Comment: @EarthMind It won't load the collection of `Answers` as collections are by [default lazy](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#fetch()). When you load a `Question` it will only load the attributes (one of them the previously calculated total number of `Answers`), but it  won't load the collection of `Answers`. Just be sure that the collection is not set to be eagerly fetched... Just to repeat: the total number of `Answers` is only calculated when an `Answer` is added or removed from a `Question`, not when a `Question` is loaded.

Comment: @Augusto Thank you for the clarification. In my case I need that data when Questions are loaded so I can put that number on the question overview page. Regarding lazy loading, I had a lot of trouble with that due to Jackson not respecting the lazy loading, so I didn't add relations by standard. I'm still trying to find a way to get the number of answers though icw Pages. It's taking me a lot of time...

Comment: Hi @EarthMind! A word of caution, tying your database objects to presentation is not a very good idea as you end up coupling your database to the presentation, which is an antipattern and you are experiencing some of the issues already. Even some people say that tying your business logic to persistent objects is also not good. My suggestion, and this is also for the maintainability of your project, create new objects which are more akin data structures to convert to json. So you have a `Question` and a `QuestionView` or `QuestionPresentation` (find out which naming suits you best).

Comment: @Augusto You're right and I should've not sticked so hard to entities by being too strict about DRY, resulting in my question also being asked in the wrong way. Focussing on this point of improvement, I managed to get it work with Page objects so now my issue is solved. I'll post an answer later so other people can have a practical example to solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem after a lot of searching and trying out and with the help of @marnish and @Augusto.

I need to start with the issue that I asked my question wrong because I wanted to know how I can implement this data into my entity, while this way of thinking was causing me to have a lot of trouble finding a solution because this limited to what I was able to achieve. It was better to separate my database object from my JSON objects because one is for persisting the data, the other for presentation to the client, and the first way hardly linked to database columns. Transient properties were no solution here either for me.

Realizing (and accepting) that, the next issue was to get the new presentation object to play nicely with Page wrappers, because I needed pagination for my Questions. This is what I wrote as solution:

**Question as an Entity linked to a database table and columns**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vragen")
// BaseEntity just contains the ID property
public class Question extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "vraag")
    private String question;

    @Column(name = "bericht")
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gebruiker")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "beantwoord", insertable = false)
    private boolean answered;

    @Column(name = "gepost_op", insertable = false)
    private Timestamp postedOn;

    @Column(name = "actief", insertable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "bekeken", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int viewed;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "vragen_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vraag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    // Thanks to @manish we can do it more efficiently instead of loading all the Answer objects
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Answer> answers;


    public Question() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

**QuestionDTO as JSON presentation object**

```
public class QuestionDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String question;
    private String message;
    private User user;
    private boolean answered;
    private Timestamp postedOn;
    private int viewed;
    private Set<Tag> tags;
    private int totalAnswers;


    public QuestionDTO() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

**The method in the QuestionServiceImpl:**

```
public Page<QuestionDTO> getAllQuestions(int page, int size, String filter) {
    List<QuestionDTO> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    Page<Question> questionPage;

    switch (filter) {
        case "popular":
            questionPage = questionRepository.findAllByActiveTrueOrderByViewedDescPostedOnDesc(PageRequest.of(page, size));
            break;

        case "answered":
            questionPage = questionRepository.findAllByActiveTrueAndAnsweredTrueOrderByPostedOnDesc(PageRequest.of(page, size));
            break;

        default:
            questionPage = questionRepository.findAllByActiveTrueOrderByPostedOnDesc(PageRequest.of(page, size));
            break;
    }

    // Here the entity data is being converted to the presentation DTO. I'm sure this can be done cleaner with for example Mapstruct as objectmapper.
    for (Question q : questionPage) {
        QuestionDTO questionDTO = new QuestionDTO();

        questionDTO.setId(q.getId());
        questionDTO.setQuestion(q.getQuestion());
        questionDTO.setMessage(q.getMessage());
        questionDTO.setUser(q.getUser());
        questionDTO.setAnswered(q.isAnswered());
        questionDTO.setPostedOn(q.getPostedOn());
        questionDTO.setViewed(q.getViewed());
        questionDTO.setTags(q.getTags());
        questionDTO.setTotalAnswers(q.getAnswers().size());

        questions.add(questionDTO);
    }
    // We want to keep all the pagination data that the method returned, so we need to wrap the questionDTO in a Page wrapper and pass all the data from Page<Question>
    return new PageImpl<>(questions, questionPage.getPageable(), questionPage.getTotalElements());
}
```

**Answer Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "antwoorden")
public class Answer extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "bericht")
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gebruiker")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vraag")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Question question;

    @Column(name = "gepost_op", insertable = false)
    private Timestamp postedOn;

    @Column(name = "actief", insertable = false)
    private boolean active;


    public Answer() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```